# Is there a convention to where manually downloaded RPMs are stored?

Tags: centos7, rpm

I need to manually download an RPM and I'm wondering if there is a convention to where this file should be stored on the system. I know I can download this to wherever, but I am curious if there is a standard or expected location to use for the system.

This is more of a standard and conventions question, I can download and install the RPM without problems.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard place to store downloaded RPM files. You can just organize somewhere for example in `/opt` some subdirectory where to store them.